# Display locally stored html file in assets folder on browser in Flutter Web

Tags: html, flutter, dart

Most answers I've seen are for mobile, but is there a way to open an HTML file stored in the asset folder on the browser in the flutter web? I've tried URL launcher but couldn't find a way to get the URL of where the asset is stored. A bunch of other solutions points back to WebView on mobile but my ask is more related to the web. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Store the HTML not in assets but in the `/web` folder where the `index.html` is.
2. Use `url_launcher` plugin to launch the address.

For example, imagine you have a `privacy.html` file you want to open from your Flutter Web app. Copy it to the `/web` folder in your project. Then use `url_launcher` and call to `launch()`:

```
launch('/privacy.html')
```

This will open a new browser tab with the HTML page.